# What kind of map art can be used for printing/wrapping onto sphere?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm working on a globe project. We need to find map art that we can modify.

What is the format/projection (?) that I would need for the map art so that it can be printed and then wrapped around a globe/sphere?

Also, where is a source for these maps?

Comment: It is unclear you are seeking data (maps) or the knowledge of how to project 2D maps onto a 3D globe, or something else.

Comment: Check on [CartoTalk](http://www.cartotalk.com) where this has come up a few times. Example thread: http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=1662

Answer (score 1):

Map projections are used to represent the Earth on a plane, but you will not be able to apply a "2D" projection back on a sphere without some "heavy" warping. The best is thus to find a pad printing device.

If you need an approximation of a by folding a plane, you can have a look at [Dymaxion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map) projection (this makes an icosahedron). You can also try with multiple [transverse Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection) projections an a spherical datum (this will make several "orange peels" (the more you make, the better it fits but you'll have to manage the junctions)